# Long import times for some modules in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I run a Python script in VS Code, it delays execution by more than a second if, for example, Pandas or Numpy are part of the script's import statement.

If only libraries from the Python Standard Library are used in the imports, the script will start immediately.

A second doesn't sound like a lot, but it is to me because I've used Spyder so far, where the same script starts immediately without spending any noticeable time on imports. I was wondering if this is normal in VS Code or if there are configuration parameters to speed up import time.

**Edit**

A minimal example would be a script with content

```
import collections
import pandas

print("a string")
```

which in my opinion should only take a few milliseconds (not noticeable) for complete processing after clicking the "run" button. Without the *pandas* import, it actually does.
I think this is an important aspect, because slow "import speeds" hinder the unit-testing workflow.

Comment: Do you mean automatic completion when importing modules? Since this function is provided by the python extension, it is recommended that you complete the loading of this extension and python language service before using this function.

Comment: @JillCheng I have added an example. IntelliSense and every other aspect of VS Code is very fast, only "warm up " time when executing the whole script is slow. I also noticed that test execution in general takes much more time (with or without pandas import) than on any other IDE I know.

Comment: VS Code as a code editor, and many of its functions need to be provided by corresponding extensions and language services. Python's debugging function is provided by the python extension, it needs to call the debugger; and the run button is to execute commands in the terminal (integrated terminal from the system) to find _python.exe_ and the executed file, so it needs a little time, but not too long.

Answer (score 0):

pandas invokes numpy, and both of those are very large packages with many C DLLs.  It takes many seconds for them to load.  Once the DLLs have been loaded into Windows file cache, it should load quicker until they age out.  It's just a fact.

Comment: The script needs the same load up time >>every<< time I run it, not just the first time. Is there something wrong with caching on my installation? In Spyder, the code above runs instantly, without "waiting" >1s before executing the print command.

Comment: Try this.  Bring up a command shell first thing in the morning.  Type `python`, then `import pandas` and see how long until the prompt returns.  Then Ctrl-Z that, and do it again.  See if the time changes.  The time depends on how much free memory you have.  Windows overall performance is way more dependent on memory than on CPU.

Comment: Interestingly, executing all three lines in a REPL opened in VS Code only delays the first execution. Caching seems to work here at least. However, the execution of a script via the "run" button is not affected. Or I misunderstood you.